# Encoding differences between using WebClient and WebRequest?

Tags: c#, webclient, webrequest

In getting some random spanish newspaper's index I don't get the diacriticals properly using WebRequest, they yield this weird character: `�`, while downloading the response from the same uri using a `WebClient` I get the appropriate response.

Why is this differentiation?

```
var client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString(endpoint);
```

vs

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing, but it's probably because `WebClient.DownloadString` looks at the `content-type` header (e.g "text/html; charset=utf-16") to infer the encoding, but your WebRequest method uses UTF8 (the default of StreamReader)

Comment: the `content-type` header isn't specifying a charset in this case.

Comment: @Nico. It should then do the tests for UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE and UTF-32 according to pre-ambles (to detect BOMs and other tell-tales) and finally defaults to the default legacy character set, which happens to match that of the site on your machine. Since HTTP assumes Latin-1 (after all, it was the early 90s) it could be well to use explicitly use that as your "I dunno" choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just assuming that the entity is in UTF-8 when creating your stream-reader without explicitly setting the encoding. You should examine the `CharacterSet` of the `HttpWebResponse` (not exposed by the `WebResponse` base class), and open the `StreamReader` with the appropriate encoding.

Otherwise, if it reads something that's not UTF-8 as if it was UTF-8, it'll come across octet-sequences that aren't valid in UTF-8 and have to substitute in U+FFFD replacement character (`�`) as the best it can do.

WebClient does pretty much this: `DownloadString` is a higher level method, that where `WebRequest` and its derived classes let you get in lower, it has a single call for "send a GET request to the URI, examine the headers to see what content-encoding is in use, in case you need to un-gzip or de-compress it, see what character-encoding is in place, set up a text-reader with that encoding and the stream, and then call `ReadAll()`". The normal high-level-big-chunk-instructions vs low-level-small-chunk-instructions pros and cons apply.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to mirror what `WebClient` specifically does change the `StreamReader` to `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Default)`

Comment: @ChrisHaas No it doesn't, that'd be just even worse - though it could possibly work in this one case - in that it would work for one legacy encoding but not for UTF-8. It examines the header and sets the correct one - which could be the same as System.Text.Encoding.Default but quite likely won't be. If there's no charset explicitly requested by the headers it tries UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE and UTF-32 in order, seeing if the result makes any sort of sense. Finally if that fails it uses its own `Encoding` property.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Granted, if it doesn't find a BOM or a zero-octet that gives the game away, and hasn't had `Encoding` explicitly set, that would result in `System.Text.Encoding.Default` being used.

Comment: I'm just saying how to mirror what `WebClient` does, not that it is good or bad. The docs say `WebClient` uses `System.Text.Encoding.Default` by default. Personally I usually inspect the raw bytes themselves when working with sites outside of my control and fallback to headers if I can't figure it out.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I see that you're right, the docs do say that. The code is better than the docs say though, if you look in ILSpy or Reflector. It first examines the Content-Type header and tries to obtain an encoding from that, then does some tests for BOMs, and then uses its `Encoding` property (which defaults to `System.Text.Encoding.Default`) as a last-resort.