# WebClient.DownloadString(url) won't work for urls that are in uni-code characters such as persian

Tags: c#, url

I am trying to get the html content from a url that has Persian characters in it such as:

> http://example.com/%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AD%DB%8C-%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%AA%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%87/website/Atelier

I am using this code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string data = client.DownloadString(urlTextWithPersianCharacters);
}
```

When the url is something like this, I get unreadable characters and symbols. This code is fine with other websites that have English urls and Persian content.

**Edit:** both answers worked find now that I am testing other websites. The problem is with one specific website that I am trying to get its content. Can the website block these kinds of requests?or use other encodings maybe?

What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: I just tested it, and I see correct persian characters using your code.

Comment: you mean you are not getting nonsense characters and symbols in `data` string?

Comment: no, I get proper persian characters. I try to open it using notepad++ and google chrome. both shows proper persian chars.

Answer (score 0):

The default `System.Text.UTF8Encoding` class is only capable of performing direct binary decoding of the `UTF-8` format. In the example you have, you are attempting to decode a URL that is using "URL Encoding".

URL encoding occurs when special characters are encoded into a URL using hex encoding with % signs as markers.

To solve this issue, you will need to decode the URL into a UTF-8 string.

The `System.Net.Uri.UnescapeDataString()` method should be able to this for you.

```
string url = "http://example.com/%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AD%DB%8C-%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%AA%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%87/website/Atelier";
string result = Uri.UnescapeDataString(url);
```

In this example, result contains: [http://example.com/طراحی-وب-سایت-آتلیه/website/Atelier](http://example.com/%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AD%DB%8C-%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%AA%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%87/website/Atelier)

**Edit:**  I did some research and saw that there are variances on how `WebClient` and `WebRequest` handle character encoding.[Link to relevant article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9019773/encoding-differences-between-using-webclient-and-webrequest).

Try switching from `WebClient` and use `WebRequest` and see if that resolves you encoding problem.

Comment: I also tried Uri.UnescapeDataString(url) but it still not working

Comment: My first approach was with `WebRequest` and `WebResponse` and I had the same result there too!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your url string to URI:

```
       Uri uri = new Uri("http://example.com/%D8%B7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%AD%DB%8C-%D9%88%D8%A8-%D8%B3%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%AA-%D8%A2%D8%AA%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%87/website/Atelier");
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    string data = client.DownloadString(uri);
}
```

Comment: I try the code and it works: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" class="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    
    <title>طراحی وب سایت آتلیه</title> ... and more html...

Comment: are you using this exact same code? it is so strange

Comment: Yes, I had copy/paste. Replace example URL by your.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods and solutions. Try which one fits your need

```
string testString = "http://test# space 123/text?var=val&another=two";
Console.WriteLine("UrlEncode:         " + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(testString));
Console.WriteLine("EscapeUriString:   " + Uri.EscapeUriString(testString));
Console.WriteLine("EscapeDataString:  " + Uri.EscapeDataString(testString));
Console.WriteLine("EscapeDataReplace: " + Uri.EscapeDataString(testString).Replace("%20", "+"));

Console.WriteLine("HtmlEncode:        " + System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(testString));
Console.WriteLine("UrlPathEncode:     " + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(testString));

//.Net 4.0+
Console.WriteLine("WebUtility.HtmlEncode: " + WebUtility.HtmlEncode(testString));
Console.WriteLine("WebUtility.UrlEncode:  " + WebUtility.UrlEncode(testString));
```